# An inequality for concave function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\left[0,1\right]  \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}
$ such that $f\left(  0\right)  =f\left(  1\right)  =0$. Suppose that $f$ is
differentiable, nonidentical zero and concave. Prove that, for $0<a<1/2$, we
have
$$
af\left(  x\right)  <f\left(  y\right)  ,
$$
for every $x\in\left[  0,1\right]  $ and $y\in\left[  a,1-a\right]  $.

I don't see the meaning of the conclusion and, also, I don't know hows to
start. Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f$ is concave, hence $f(x)\ge (1-x)f(0)+xf(1)=0$ for all $0\le x\le 1$. By the assumption that $f(x)$ is not identically $0$, there is $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$. We find that for all $x\in (0,x_0]$,
$$
f(x) \ge \frac{x}{x_0}f(x_0)+\left(1-\frac{x}{x_0}\right)f(0)>0,
$$  and similarly that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in [x_0,1)$. This shows $f(x)>0$ for all $0<x<1$. And the given inequality for $x\in \{0,1\}$ is established.

Now, suppose $x\in (0,1)$ and $y\in [a,1-a]$. We find that
$$
0< z := \frac{y-ax}{1-a}< 1.
$$ This gives
$$
f(y) = f(ax + (1-a)z)\ge af(x)+(1-a)f(z)>af(x)
$$ and the given inequality follows.

Comment: Does the differentiability matter?

Comment: @stefano Umm ... it turns out that differentiability is not really necessary.